# Spring boot application to run parllel querys with multiple jdbc connections

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jdbc

I am looking for technical solution to query data from one db and load it into a SQL Server database using java spring boot standalone application.

```
select a.student_id
max(decode(a.marks_limit, 99.99,100,null )) as max_marks,
b.student_city_code "NYC",
from student a, student_info b
where a.student_id=b.student_id
and a.student_id in (''a123,'b123','c123')
and  b.adress_modified > TO_TIMESTAMP('2018/09/13 10:13:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
group by a.student_id, b.student_city_code
```

We are running this oracle query serially and its taking 1 hour execution and ~30 million records, for better results planning to split this query into 3 similar queries, so instead of using in operator planning to use = in each query like a.student_id="a123" in one query and a.student_id="b123" in second query a.student_id="b123" in third, I believe 1 hours time will reduced to ~20min each query execution.

As a technical solution of it planning to execute all the multiple queries parallelly and commit the results to target table parallelly using Oracle batch streaming. As I know Oracle JDBC driver supports kind of streaming. When we iterate over ResultSet it loads only fetchSize rows into memory.

Please help with sample code base how to open multiple source and destination JDBC connection dynamically and close is after completion of process. Java8 has extensive package. Please suggest if you  have any better solution for it.

```
oracle-jdbc-con1     oracle-jdbc-con2        oracle-jdbc-con3
       |                   |                   |        
       |                   |                   | 
       V                   V                   V 
sql-jdbc-con1          sql-jdbc-con2         sql-jdbc-con3
```

Comment: Why do you need to use spring boot to do this? seems like overkill.

Comment: Is should run continusely 24/7 or every 1hour also Our project demands it, so we need to go for that

Answer (score 0):

Any type of program will be an overhead. Also, I assume it's one time activity which doesn't require an application to do it.

We recently migrated couple of tables from MySQL to MS SQL Server and after trying with couple of option we used SSMA.

SSMA is MS Sql Server's own tool to bring database or schema or tables from other databases. When you migrate, let's say single table from oracle to sql server, it takes care of datatype conversion as well.

All you need is to 
- install SSMA (windows only)
- configure source and destination datasources
- select database objects on a windows application
- click migrate

SSMA has it's own version specifically for Oracle `OracleToSQL`
Here is an [introductory Documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/getting-started-with-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017), however you will find plenty of step-by-step guides.